# SQL Server - Tables Specific to Each User

Tags: sql-server

Here's my scenario:

User inputs date range. Stored Procedure runs, which populates other tables based on dates. User can then click a button to view these tables (another SP which selects from the tables).

Issue:

There are multiple users. Each users needs to be able to have their own tables, so to speak, because date ranges can be different. Right now, user 1 runs SP which populates table for dates A and B. Then user 2 runs SP which populates table for dates C and D. Now user 1 goes and clicks view button, expecting the data for dates A and B but what happens is data for C and D shows up because the last user who ran the SP used dates C and D.

How can I keep the data separate/local for each user?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you caching the query results in the first place?

Comment: Why do you need to have different tables for each user again?  Surely one table with a field identifying the user the data is intended for will do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to store the query results, then you need to key the result set, either on the user, or generating a scenario ID each time the user runs the report.

The simplest approach is to just run the query as a report and not store the results.  Recalculate the output and just dump it each time the user runs the report (i.e. don't
store ther results).

If you do need to store the results *and* each user only needs to work with one date range at any given time, then the table can be annotated with a user ID.

If a user can work with more than one scenario, then there needs to be another control table with the scenarios for each user.  When the user does a run then a new scenario ID is genereated.  You will need a screen to allow users to select the scenario in this case, and probably some means of cleaning out obsolete ones.

Comment: To expand, user is inputting the daterange for orders to include. The SP then gets all orders within this date range (thousands), all items (thousands) and line items (thousands) and returns values on how much these orders are worth, how much we can produce etc. The SP execution time is long. Then user wants to see which orders and which items/orders make up these values so he clicks "view". And it's at that point when I bring up the data from these tables. So I do need to store the results, and it seems the user ID column is the recommended approach. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, you might want to look at putting this into a SSAS cube and using that to do the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You could add one more column to the table, and then when you populate it with data add a session variable / user id to this column.

The query that then selects from this table would then need to be updated to select where the session variable / user id matches.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are deleting the whole table each time, instead try deleting just the data for the user who is running the query. Use a WHERE clause on the SELECT so each user only sees their own data. This would imply that you need to store the user name/ID with each row of data if you are not already.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing a user ID with each added value, and then pass in the user ID in all your queries. That way you can use 1 table and 1 stored procedure.

So if user A runs the stored procedure it will add records A-1A, A-2A.
When user B runs the stored procedure it will add records B-1B, B-2B, B-3B etc.

When you click the view button, simply call a second stored procedure where you pass the user ID again, and it returns rows for that user ID.