# Source File Connection (Flat File) - Not reading column metadata

Tags: csv, ssis, metadata, flat-file

When I create the SSIS package it requires a file to be referenced to pick up the files metadata. For example the column headers will be ColumnA, ColumnB.

I have always assumed that these column names need to be present in the file for it to be loaded. Recently business, for whatever reason, changed one of the column names in the file to something else so the file contains ColumnA, NotColumnB. When the SSIS package runs it ignores this and loads the file. I assumed that it would fail. Is my assumption correct and there is something weird going on or is my assumption incorrect, if so please let me know why.

I have changed the column names in a few other packages that load data from a file and they also dont care what the column names are

Comment: Are you changing the column names in the flat file connection manager or the flat file source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the flat file source, and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties tab. There are a property called `ValidateExternalMetadata` change it to `True`.

For more information check the following answer:

- [Detect new column in source not mapped to destination and fail in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837915/detect-new-column-in-source-not-mapped-to-destination-and-fail-in-ssis/54840947#54840947)

---

### Update 1

It looks like that flat file connection manager has no validation engine and the metadata defined is used at configuration time to configure the mappings between the data file and the database.

- [Why Does't SSIS Flat File Data Check If Columns Names or Order Have Changed? What is best way to check?](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/6239/why-doest-ssis-flat-file-data-check-if-columns-nam.html)
- [Flat file destination columns data types validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951462/flat-file-destination-columns-data-types-validation/54953976#54953976)

Comment: Business changed the source file not the metadata in teh connection manager. Yea, we changed that property before I posted this and it was already set to True. Is there perhaps a project level parameter that needs to get set to enable this?

Comment: In the flat file connection manager, did you checked the `First row contains header` property?